# What causes "'void' type not allowed here" error

Tags: java

When I try to compile this:

```
import java.awt.* ;

    class obj
    {
        public static void printPoint (Point p) 
        { 
            System.out.println ("(" + p.x + ", " + p.y + ")"); 
        }
        public static void main (String[]arg)
        {
            Point blank = new Point (3,4) ; 
            System.out.println (printPoint (blank)) ;
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

```
obj.java:12: 'void' type not allowed here
        System.out.println (printPoint (blank)) ; 
                                               ^
1 error
```

I don't really know how to start asking about this other than to ask:

- What went wrong here?
- What does this error message mean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If a method returns `void` then there is nothing to print, hence this error message. Since printPoint already prints data to the console, you should just call it directly:

```
printPoint (blank);
```

Answer (score 16):

You are trying to print the result of `printPoint` which doesn't return anything.  You will need to change your code to do either of these two things:

```
class obj
{
    public static void printPoint (Point p) 
    { 
        System.out.println ("(" + p.x + ", " + p.y + ")"); 
    }
    public static void main (String[]arg)
    {
        Point blank = new Point (3,4) ; 
        printPoint (blank) ;
    }
}
```

or this:

```
class obj
{
    public static String printPoint (Point p) 
    { 
        return "(" + p.x + ", " + p.y + ")"; 
    }
    public static void main (String[]arg)
    {
        Point blank = new Point (3,4) ; 
        System.out.println (printPoint (blank)) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The type problem is that `println` takes a String to print, but instead of a string, you're calling the `printPoint` method which is returning `void`.

You can just call `printPoint(blank);` in your main function and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the result of `printPoint()` - which is void - to the `println()` function.

Answer (score 1):

`printPoint` prints by itself rather than returning a string. To fix that call `printPoint` (blank) without the `System.out.println`.

A better alternative may be: make `printPoint(Point p)` return a string (and change its name to something like `FormatPoint`), that way the method may be used to format a point for the console, GUI, print, etc rather than being tied to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to do : `printPoint (blank);`. Looks like you are trying to print twice; once inside `printPoint()` and once inside `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.* ;
 
class Main
{
    public static void printPoint (Point p) 
    { 
        System.out.println ("(" + p.x + ", " + p.y + ")"); 
    }
    public static void main (String[]arg)
    {
        Point blank = new Point (3,4) ; 
         printPoint (blank) ;
    }
}
```

//you can't print the value while its not returnring anything in function try this one