# void type not allowed here (java) (s != null)

Tags: java

I have this code, it says void type not allowed here (where I put the //error comment)
When I delete the &&..... it wont give the error

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
if (ae.getSource() == ok) {
    Contact nweC = null;


    String vnm = tfVoor.getText();
    String anm = tfAchter.getText();
    String em = tfEmail.getText();
    if (em.trim().length() > 0 && !hetBoek.heeftContact(em)) {
        nweC = new Contact(vnm, anm, em);
    } else {
        tfEmail.setText("");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Onjuist emailadres", "Mislukt", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    //error if (nweC != null && hetBoek.voegContactToe(nweC)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Toevoegen gelukt", "Succes", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
} else if (ae.getSource() == cancel) {
    tfVoor.setText("");
    tfAchter.setText("");
    tfEmail.setText("");
} else if (ae.getSource() == toon) {
    String s = hetBoek.toString();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s, "Druk op OK",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
}
```

I hope someone can help me! thanks

Comment: I assume hetBoek.voegContactToe(nweC) is declared with a void type. What would you expect if ((void)method) to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['void' type not allowed here error (java) help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442675/void-type-not-allowed-here-error-java-help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hetBoek.voegContactToe(nweC)` returns `void`(nothing). It must return a `boolean` to use it in a expression in the `if` statement

Comment: Thanks, im not really experienced, so I don't know why people start voting this down. I know it's a noob question, but I got it fixed thanks to these answers!

Answer (score 3):

`hetBoek.voegContactToe(nweC)` returns a void . You should have `boolean` types in `if()`

Answer (score 3):

The method `hetBoek.voegContactToe` is most likely `void`. It does not return a value, so what was your intention when using it in an `if` statement:

```
if (nweC != null && hetBoek.voegContactToe(nweC)) {
```

Should the method return `boolean` instead of `void`?

Answer (score 3):

I think this mehod's return type is void

```
hetBoek.voegContactToe(nweC);
```

Its return type should be boolean.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the boolean in

```
public boolean hetBoek.voegContactToe(Contact contact)


if (e1 op1 e2 op2 e3 ... )
{
...
}
```

e - expressions that need to return a boolean value

Answer (score 2):

currently `hetBoek.voegContactToe(nweC);` is void.
It return type should be boolean.

Find your method `voegContactToe`() and change it's reutrn type to boolean and add return statement as per the logic.