# String Method-converting string to char then display the characters with a specified index

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to make a code regarding string methods  that accepts a string and returns the value of getChars. Indexes or indices should be an input from the user. A string should be converted to an array of character which will be used as destination. However, I'm having some confusing errors.

Any help?
Here's the code/.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Exercise5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Stay Calm and Be Cool!
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string = new String();

        System.out.print("Enter any String: ");
        string = a.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter source begin index: ");
        int begin = a.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter source end index: ");
        int end = a.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter destination index: ");
        int dest = a.nextInt();

        char[] sample = string.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("The value extracted from " + string + " with indexes "+ begin + " to "+ end + " is: " + 
                string.getChars(begin, end, sample, dest));
    }

}
```

ERROR: void is not allowed. ---how to get rid of that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442675/void-type-not-allowed-here-error-java

Comment: What `char[] sample = string.toCharArray(sample);` is supposed to do? Which method are you trying to invoke? Can you link its JavaDoc because I don't see any `toCharArray` which accepts char[].

Comment: Sorry, the sample must not be inside that paranthesis...

Answer (score 1):

`String#getChars` do not return any value, it writes the result into `dest` parameter:

```
final int length = end - begin;
char[] sample = new char[length];
string.getChars(begin, end, sample, dest);
System.out.println("The value extracted from " + string + " with indexes "+ begin + " to "+ end + " is: " + sample);
```